# How a for in loop in python ends when there is no update statement in it?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, variables, increment

For example:

```py
#1
val = 5
for i in range(val) :
    print(i)
```

When the range is exhausted i.e. last value reached how python knows for in loop ends . As in other languages

```
#2
for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
    print(i)
}
```

As in this exp. when i's values becomes larger than 5 false condition leads to termination of loop .

I tried reading docs of python and browsed over google but no satisfying answer.  So unable to get a picture of this .

Comment: "how python knows for in loop ends" Because it isn't a C-style loop. It works nothing like that. It is an iterator-based for-loop. There is no "increment". This is [clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). For loops use [the iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) to handle arbitrary iterables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is actually a complicated question, but the very rough version of the answer is "the compiler/interpreter can do what it wants".

It isn't actually running the human-readable text you write at all - instead it goes through a whole pipeline of transformations. At minimum, a lexer converts the text to a sequence of symbols, and then a parser turns that into a tree of language constructs; that may then be compiled into machine code or interpreted by a virtual machine.

So, the python interpreter creates a structure that handles the underlying logic. Depending on the optimizations performed (those are really a black box, it's hard to say what they do), this may be producing structures logically equivalent to what a Java-like `for` loop would make, or it could actually create a data structure of numbers (that's what the `range()` function does on its own) and then iterate over them.

Editing to give some more foundation for what this construct even means:

Python iteration-style loops are different in how they're defined from C-style `i++` sorts of loops. Python loops are intended to iterate on each element of a list or other sequence data structure - you can say, for instance, `for name in listOfNames`, and then use `name` in the following block.

When you say `for i in range(x)`, this is the pythonic way of doing something like the C-style loop. Think of it as the reverse of

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    foo(arr[i[)
}
```

In that code block you're accessing each element of an indexible sequence `arr` by going through each valid index. You don't actually care about `i` - it's just a means to an end, a way to make sure you visit each element.

Python assumes that's what you're trying to do: the python variant is

```
for elem in arr:
   foo(elem)
```

Which most people would agree is simpler, clearer and more elegant.

However, there are times when you actually do want to explicitly go number by number. To do that with a python style, you create a list of all the numbers you'll want to visit - that's what the `range` function does. You'll mostly see it as part of a loop statement, but it can exist independently - you can say `x = range(10)`, and `x` will hold a list that consists of the numbers 0-9 inclusive.

So, where before you were incrementing a number to visit each item of a list, now you're taking a list of numbers to get incrementing values.

"How it does this" is still explanation I gave above - the parser and interpreter know how to create the nitty-gritty logic that actually creates this sequence and step through it, or possibly transform it into some logically equivalent steps.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't really address the question and frankly, seems like a lot of hand-waving. Python for-loops aren't that complicated, they are clearly documented and follow a clearly defined protocol.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga He's asking "how it knows" - to me, that says he's asking about the mechanism by which the interpreter can correctly run such a construct. The answer to that involves understanding the structure of an interpreter - obviously that's beyond the scope of a single answer, but I think a high-level (and, yes, handwavey) overview could help give some intuition.

Comment: My impression, at least, was that he was unclear on how Python could execute such a statement when the logic to do so is not laid out in the code as explicitly as it is in other languages.

Comment: @EdwardPeters , exactly, I am just trying to understand background mechanism .

Comment: @Kafka2701 So I edited my answer to include a lot more of what the meaning and motivation of the python-style loop is. The background style mechanism involves a lot of stuff on how an interpreter works - if you want I can write about that at greater length, but you're probably better off googling. (It's an advanced topic a lot of programmers never really understand - I think it's worth learning, but there's a lot to it.)